# Javascript onsubmit not running

Tags: javascript

I know very little javascript. after going page to page, I created this, hoping this would work. but for some reason, I have no idea why this doesn't work.

```
<form onsubmit="goToPage()" method="get">
<input id="url">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<script>

function goToPage()
{
var initial = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/";
window.location.replace(initial+document.getElementById("url").value);
}
</script>
```

Now, I thought when I submitted the form, It would run `toToPage()`, and redirect me to the embedded version for youtube. However, it's not.

I found that I could do `onclick="goToPage()"` for the input, but I don't want to have to click the input. I want the ability to either click "enter" or click on submit.

Comment: Seems working to me: http://jsfiddle.net/67G8E/

Comment: Does not work for me on firefox or chrome. Not sure why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must return **false** in onsubmit function, so the page will redirect not submitted by form.

```
<form onsubmit="return goToPage()" method="get">
<input id="url">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<script>

function goToPage() {
    var initial = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/";
    window.location.replace(initial+document.getElementById("url").value);
    //window.location.href = initial + document.getElementById("url").value;
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: @user2179524 It's not very nice that you accept his answer when I told you to do it in mine and in a comment. But I guess it wasn't clear. Good luck

Comment: @NicoSantangelo - Don't take offense, but your answer was missing a key bit of code. Even with the `return false;` added to the `goToPage()` function it wouldn't have worked, because the HTML still had `onsubmit="goToPage()"` instead of the necessary `onsubmit="return goToPage()"`. So the `false` return value from `goToPage()` would be discarded instead of being passed back to the browser as needed.

Comment: Yes, it's fine, I'm going to delete my answer :)